# Samesite cookie error in Karate feature file

Tags: karate, samesite

Whenever I get the token from openid I get the error also and my Karate feature becomes failure:

io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.DefaultCookie.sameSite()Lio/netty/handler/codec/http/cookie/CookieHeaderNames$SameSite;

Did a lot of hit and trial but failed to get the answer. Please give me some way to get out from this issue.

I tried putting the value LAX, Strict and None in the feature but not working

Comment: this is most likely an old version of karate or a library conflict. see if using the `all` classifier helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-core-fat-jar - if still stuck, it is important that you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helps. "all classifier". Thanks a ton.